# How to check if an item is selected in TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I check if an item is selected in a TreeView?

I want to check if anything is selected, not a specific item.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The TreeView class has a SelectedNode property that holds the currently selected TreeNode.

```
TreeNode tn = ctl_treeView.SelectedNode;

if ( tn == null )
    Console.WriteLine("No tree node selected.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Selected tree node {0}.", tn.Name );
```

You can compare the returned TreeNode reference to the TreeNode you're looking for, and so check if it's currently selected.

Comment: treeView does not contain a definition of SelectedNode. I get this compile time error.

Answer (score 4):

To check the selected status of a specific item, you can explicitly reference the node you want to check and return its `IsSelected` property.  Like this:

Assuming a TreeView structured as follows:

Node0
+--- Node3
Node1
Node2
+--- Node4   **<-- **you want to check this Node****
+--- Node5

Your code could look like this:

```
bool isSelected = treeView1.Nodes["Node2"].Nodes["Node4"].IsSelected;
```